# The blue area (weight painting) still moves when a bone is moved. Why the hell does this happen?

Tags: weight-painting

This is a simple character model where the arms/legs etc are all boxes disconnected from another. There are no faces connecting the arms to the torso for example.

[image]

Comment: Share the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some vertices may appear blue but it doesn't mean there are not part of the vertex group, with an influence of 0.01 they will appear blue. If you want to have a real preview you need to switch the *Viewport Overlay > Weight Paint > Zero Weight* from *None* to *Active*. Now black is real 0%.

[image]

If you want to make sure that some parts of your mesh are not part of a vertex group, select these vertices in *Edit* mode and in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Group*, select the group and click on *Remove* or *Remove From All Groups*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.